# ¿Cómo invertir una lista con el uso de nodos?

Tags: java

No soy capaz de invertir la lista mediante el método `reverse`. El método reverse tiene que darle la vuelta a la lista. Por ejemplo, lista principal: (1,2,3,4) resultado: (4,3,2,1).

Esto es lo que llevo en el código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Lista lista = new Lista();
    lista.insertarOrden(2);
    lista.insertarOrden(4);
    lista.insertarOrden(5);
    lista.insertarOrden(7);
    lista.insertarOrden(9);
    lista.reverse();
}

public class Lista {
    public class Nodo {
        int info;
        private Nodo sig;
        public Nodo (int info) {
            this.info = info;
            sig = null;
        }
    }

    private Nodo primero;

    public void reverse () {
        Nodo aux = primero;
        while (aux != null) { //2,4,5,7
             aux = aux.sig;
             if (aux.sig == null) {
                aux = primero;
             }else {
                aux = aux.sig;
             }
             System.out.println(aux.info);
             aux = aux.sig;
        }
        System.out.println(aux.info);
    }

    public void insertarOrden (int valor) {
        if (primero == null) {
             primero = new Lista.Nodo(valor);
        }else {
             if (primero.info > valor) {
                 Lista.Nodo aux = new Lista.Nodo(valor);
                 aux.sig = primero;
                 primero = aux;
             }else {
                 Lista.Nodo aux = primero;
                 while (aux.sig != null && aux.sig.info < valor) {
                     aux = aux.sig;
                 }
                 Lista.Nodo nuevo = new Lista.Nodo(valor);
                 nuevo.sig = aux.sig;
                 aux.sig = nuevo;
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: el metodo `reverse` es uno especifico o puedes plantear el algoritmo como se te ocurra?

Comment: tengo que plantear el algoritmo como se me ocurra

Comment: el método reverse tiene que seleccionar el nodo anterior? o que tiene que hacer exactamente?

Comment: por favor explica que tiene que hacer reverse.

Comment: el método reverse tiene que invertir una lista por ejemplo si la lista principal es (1,2,3,4) que la modifique para que sea (4,3,2,1)

Comment: es decir que el método reverse tiene que darle la vuelta a la lista para ponerla al revés.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si puedes presentar cualquier solución posiblemente lo más fácil sea crear una nueva lista al revés a partir de la vieja. Por lo que veo antes de poder hacer esto tendrías que tener un nuevo método para insertar nodos a la lista porque tu método actual mete los valores más alto al final de la lista. Algo así como:

```
public void insertarDesorden (int valor) {
    if (primero == null) {
         primero = new Lista.Nodo(valor);
    }else {
        Lista.Nodo aux = new Lista.Nodo(valor);
        aux.sig = primero;
        primero = aux;
        Lista.Nodo nuevo = new Lista.Nodo(valor);
        nuevo.sig = aux.sig;
        aux.sig = nuevo;
    }
}
```

Y en tu método `reverse` algo así como:

```
public void reverse () {
    Lista nuevaLista = new Lista();
    while (this.primero != null) { //2,4,5,7
        Nodo aux = primero;
        while (aux.sig != null){
            aux = aux.sig;
        }
        nuevaLista.insertarDesorden(aux.info);
        aux = null;
    }
    return nuevaLista;
}
```

El objetivo es dejar la lista original vacía. Iterar para siempre llegar al nodo final e ir metiendo al valor del nodo final a la nueva lista.

Estoy un poco oxidado en Java, éste código no es algo probado y en realidad nunca he hecho algo así fuera de C, pero espero que de menos la respuesta te dé una idea de cómo seguir.

Answer (score 0):

```
int longitud(){
     NodoInt actual = this.primero;
     int lon = 0;
     while(actual!=null){
         lon++;
         actual = actual.siguiente;
     }
     return lon;
 }


 public void reverse (){

     int cont=this.longitud();
     while(cont>0){
        NodoInt actual =this. primero;

        while (actual.siguiente != null) { 

             if (actual.siguiente.siguiente == null) {
                System.out.print(actual.siguiente.elemento + " ");
                actual.siguiente=null;
              }
             else {
                actual = actual.siguiente;

                 }
            }
        cont --;
    }
System.out.print(primero.elemento);
}
```